# PHP mail() with From: header prevents delivery

Tags: php, email

First things first... I know mail deliverability is effected by hundreds of factors and so it's never possible to say for SURE if one specific thing is the cause. (I do *not* expect this.)

My question is whether is normal/expected for mail servers to block messages which have a different `From:` header. My contact form handler uses this so that the reciptient can reply to the sender (code below). Gmail accounts are able to receive the messages. But my client has an institutional `.edu` email address and the emails aren't getting delivered.

Here's a minimal version of my code:

```
<?php 

$first_name = 'John';
$last_name = 'Smithy';
$email = "myemail@whyisntthisworking.com";
$msg = "This is a test email. If you received it things are working.";

$test_email = (isset($_POST['test_email'])) ? $_POST['test_email'] : FALSE;

$to;
$from = $email;
$subject = "Contact from JamesGregoryMD.com";
$body = wordwrap( "{$first_name} {$last_name}:\n\n{$msg}\n\n{$email}\n{$phone}", 70);
$headers = "From: {$from}" . "\r\n";

if ($test_email) {
    # send email
    $return = mail($test_email,"Test email",$body, $headers);

    if ($return) {
        echo "<h1>MAIL SENT</h1>";
    } else {
        echo "<h1>MAIL NOT SENT</h1>";
    }
}
?>

<form id="contact" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="test_email" placeholder="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: Ever thought that their or your server might be blocking some of the other servers?

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you expand slightly on what that means? I'm testing of my own server which is a Bluehost VPS (that *should* have a clean IP). The live site will be a standard Dreamhost shared hosting account.

Comment: I'd contact your host to see why that is. Any way you can test it on the/a live server now?

Comment: Actually, there might be... because I think Dreamhost assigns a random subdomain automatically. I'm going to look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Reply-To:` header instead of `From:` and you likely won't have that problem (but will get the same functionality).

Comment: Thanks. Would I also use a different `From:` header? Or omit it entirely?

Comment: The `From:` header should be one that actually resolves to the machine you're sending the mail from. So, if your machine sits on `example.com`, you would be better off setting it to a valid address `@example.com`.

Comment: What if there are no email hosted on the domain? For example, a university professor that uses the school's .edu address but has his/her own personal .com site. Should the `From:` header be unspecified/default?

Comment: I would need to know the specifics, i.e., is there an error message from this particular user's mail server while delivering the message? What `From:` address are you using now that makes it through GMail but not the university server? Edit: There's a chance that they're validating the `From:` address, and if it doesn't exist, then it fails. If you're using a made-up address, maybe try using a legitimate one? You also might try omitting the `From:` header altogether and just using whatever PHP is setup for. The `Reply-To:` will still work.

Comment: It's a contact form. So the From: / Reply-To: is set dynamically based on the input from the sender. I want the recipient to be able to reply to the user (not the server)

Comment: That is exactly what `Reply-To:` will handle for you. Replies will go to that address, regardless of what is set in the `From:` address. It is listed under "RFCs." on this page - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Message_header

Answer (score 1):

What you are effectively doing is "spoofing" the From address. This is perfectly acceptable according to the definition of SMTP, but only because when the Internet was young, nobody thought that it would be abused. Unfortunately, this leaves the door wide open to spammers, so various checks are generally implemented which you may be running into:

- When connecting to an SMTP server (to deliver mail to a user on that domain), the client sends a "HELO" (or extended "EHLO") message with their identity. Some servers will reject messages where this doesn't match the `From` header. Depending on the setup, you may get some joy be adding `"-f$from_address"` as the 5th parameter to the `mail()` function.
- Other servers may verify that you're actually connecting from the domain mentioned in that parameter, so still won't like it.
- More sophisticated systems will check DNS records on the domain of the from address for allowed sender information. Look up "SPF" and "DKIM" online and you should find info on how to check and set them up.

Comment: Thanks. Is this how the first suggestion should look? `mail($test_email,"Test email",$body, $headers,"-f$from_address" )`

Comment: @SDP Pretty much; looking at your existing code, I notice it will be `"-f$from"` in your case.